# Host is unreachable by SSH while running Ansible playbook

Tags: ssh, ansible

Host is unreachable by SSH while running Ansible playbook. Ran Ansible playbook on 15 hosts, 13 were provisioned successfully, 1 was unreachable even though they were configured the same. Here is the actual error received. Can anyone help? Thx

fatal: [Host]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: FIPS mode initialized\r\nDisabling GSSAPIKeyExchange. Not usable in FIPS mode\r\n
…
\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive).", "unreachable": true}

Comment: What have you done to diagnose this so far? The first step is probably to run `ansible-playbook -vvv ...` so that you can see the actual ssh commands ansible is using, then try to reproduce the problem from the command line yourself.

Comment: Before running the playbook, you can try `ansible <GROUP> -m ping -i <HOSTS_INVENTORY>` to see which machines are reachable

Comment: @larsks Thx for feedback!  I did run that command and seems to be using the correct IP addresses when SSH'ing.  What else should I be looking for when trying to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @dejdej  I'm sorry, I'm an Ansible newbie.  How do I know which GROUP to use in this command?  Where do I find it?  Thx.

Comment: @dejdej Nevermind, I tried that and I was able to reach that specific host.

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive)

you may check permission of .ssh/authorized_keys.
seem issue of your public key of destination server.